# Using Google Sheets, can I let people assign themselves a role(or tag), and then have them appear in another table as options for that role?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create two tables, the first is one that lets people assign themselves various roles. Then in a second table, I want to be able to choose from various roles and have the names of the people assigned to those roles appear in another drop down below their role. Below is an example
[A mock up of the roles table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TdPV.png)

So for example, if Greg assigns himself as an Electrician and Labourer in the first table, then anywhere I have an Electrician or Labourer selected on my second table, Greg will appear in the drop down below as an option.

Ideally the second table will also return errors for using the same person twice, or remove them from the options available if they are already selected elsewhere.

I have created a fairly limited version using Named Date Ranges pulled from a filter of the first table, but have no idea where to go from here when it comes to automating who appears on the second table based on the role selected. I am just doing it manually for now. I am applying this on a much larger scale than the example provided, so the manual input is quite limiting.

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HYn8wsSaaPQcKC6_nglm6MibbR6O1raDKhBbsj2hrq0/edit?usp=sharing) to my example spreadsheet.